# Update the index of suggestion list in autocompletetextview on textchange

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using autocomplete textview with arraylist value [aaa0,aaa1,...aaa100,aab0,aab1,...,aab100], I enter value 'aa' and scroll down till next 10 value ie.'aa10'and then i enter value 'aab' the suggestion list starts from 10th value i.e 'aab10'.
I have to scroll up to see the first value i.e 'aab0'.I want first value of suggestion list to appear when i change the search text.[suggestion list screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfUfD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the **AutoCompleteTextView** class 
and override the **onFilterComplete** method 
where you have to dismiss and show the drop down again to refresh the list view.

Also I would suggest instead of extending **AutoCompleteTextView** 
extend the **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView**
for obviously better support

here's the code

```
package your.package.name;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.support.v7.widget.*;

public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {

       public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

       public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       }

      @Override
      public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
           super.onFilterComplete(count);
           //show and dismiss the drop down to refresh the list in it
           this.dismissDropDown();
           this.showDropDown();
      }
 }
```

**EDIT**

Also you can use the AutoCompleteTextView.setListSelection() method to scroll to the top.
Instead of dismissing and showing the DropDown on every filter
which is more efficient.

```
      @Override
      public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
           super.onFilterComplete(count);
           //set list selection to 0
           if(getListSelection() != 0)
                 this.setListSelection(0);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..I cannot dismiss the drop down on every filter performed.I need to only scroll the list to top on filter performed without dismissing the dropdown

Comment: @MaheshAmbekar Check out the edit. Exactly what you want i guess